# symfony: how "svn revert ." works?

Tags: svn, revert

i've done a checkout, after that i modify a file that has been download.

Then i do `svn revert .` where the file is, expecting it has again the contents that has after doing the checkout but it has the modification i have made after.

So how can i go the state of the file after doing the checkout?

Javier

Comment: what version of svn do you use ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the recursive flag

```
svn revert -R .
```

Your command will only revert things on the folder, e.g. svn-property changes, not on files or folders below.

Answer (score 0):

You could also DELETE the changed file, then do an UPDATE from anyplace above it on the folder tree.

SVN "updates" missing files by putting them back!